# What is the lining of "Silver-lined" gloves actually made of?

Tags: silver, gloves

I bought some rubber gloves that claim to be "Silver-lined".  I think this is supposed to make the gloves easier to put on and take off.  Is there an actual silver compound lining the gloves that makes them slippery?

For example these gloves [here](https://visual-123.myshopify.com/collections/personal-protective-equipment/products/pro-val-tuff-pinks-silver-lined-rubber-gloves) are only $3.30.  And the description is as follows: "Silver lining enables easy on/off glide and eliminates particle shedding from the glove.".

Comment: Are you talking about [Silver Sheild](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/z529575?lang=en&region=US&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItPvG1Obc3gIVpf_jBx0LTw7wEAAYASAAEgLZL_D_BwE) gloves?

Comment: No, these are fairly regular rubber gloves,  for example, http://www.highgategroup.net.au/silver-lined-rubber-gloves-blue

Comment: I don’t see any reason not to assume that they have a very thin silver lining. As in actual metallic silver. Very thin layers cost almost nothing.

Comment: True, but it's surprising how hard it is to get any actual information about these things!

Comment: its just a different colour, they use a process called chlorination witch makes them glide on and off, otherwise things would stick, alot of latex fashion clothing is chlorinated and even disposable latex gloves but not nitrile,